# How do I not select a row from sets with null and not null in SQL?

Tags: sql, null

I have tried to find this on SO.

I have a table,

```
id   | col2 | col3
----   ----   ----
5     smith   (null)
5     smith  100
12    Jackson 356
12    Jackson 400
8     Johnson (null)
9     bob     1200
```

In this scenario I only want the rows from a set where the same id only has one non-null.  In other words, I don't want smith, I don't want Johnson.  I only want Jackson and bob.

I have tried,

```
select * from table 
where is not null a
nd not exists (select * from table where is null)
```

I can't get it to work.

Comment: Why don't you want smith given it has only one non-null?

Comment: Why do you want Jackson when it has two non-null rows?

Comment: @Yang because I don't need that set of records.  I need to have sets of records that have no nulls.

Comment: @DStanley because that is the type of set I need.  I need sets of values.

Comment: No nulls or just one non-null?  Those are different.

Comment: @johnny the problem is that you said that you want ids that only have one non null, and then you go to say you want rows that have more than one non null value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` but include a WHERE to reference each id:

```
select * 
from yourtable t
where col3 is not null 
  and not exists (select id 
                  from yourtable d
                  where d.col3 is null
                   and t.id = d.id);
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06684/7)

Answer (score 2):

Your statement and desired results don't quite match, but this will give you every ID that does not have a NULL value in column 3:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE id NOT IN
(SELECT ID FROM table WHERE col3 IS NULL)
```

If you want records with just one non-null (which you state but your expected result doesn't match, use

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE id NOT IN
(SELECT ID 
 FROM table 
 WHERE col3 IS NOT NULL 
 GROUP BY ID 
 HAVING COUNT(id) = 1
)
```